# Stack overflow error during recursive String operation

Tags: java, string, methods, substring

I'm trying to recursively add a dash in between of a string but it's not working, and it's giving me a stack overflow error. Here's my code:

```
public static String expand (String word)
{

    int stringLength = word.length ();
    String expandedWord = word;

    if (stringLength <= 1)
    {
        return expandedWord;
    }
    else
    {
        expandedWord = word.substring (0, (stringLength - stringLength) + 1) + "-" + word.substring ((stringLength - stringLength) + 1, stringLength);
        stringLength++;
        expand(word);

        return expandedWord;
    }


}
```

Comment: `word` never changes, your recursive doesn't end.

Comment: `(stringLength - stringLength) + 1` always gives you 1 by the way

Comment: Im confused. Help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When writing a recursive algorithm, you need to think of two things.

1. What are my end states?
2. How do I reduce the problem complexity?

In your case, you've correctly isolated the end state: if you are passed a string of length 1, then you need to do nothing.

The second stage is where you're getting confused.

In order to recursively add hyphens between all characters, you need to:

1. Take off the first character
2. Add a hyphen
3. Run the full algorithm on the rest of the string

The below code should indicate this:

```
public static String expand(String word)
{
    if (word.length() <= 1)
    {
        // My end state: the input string has 0 or 1 characters - no way to add hyphens!
        return word;
    }
    else
    {
        // Return the first character of word, a hyphen, and the result of the recursive algorithm
        return word.substring(0, 1) + "-" + expand(word.substring(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static String expand (String word)
{

    int stringLength = word.length ();
    String expandedWord = word;

    if (stringLength <= 1)
    {
        return expandedWord;
    }
    else
    {
        expandedWord = word.substring (0, 1) + "-" + expand(word.substring(1, stringLength));

        return expandedWord;
    }
}
```

Not thoroughly tested though.

Comment: Doesnt work. Although the reason is probably caused by my garbage code.